# GWT Autobean Codex reading a Map

Tags: java, json, gwt, gxt, autobean

I have a JSON map like:

```
{ "element":"value","element2":"value2",...}
```

With both key and value strings. I try to read it with an autobean and I get strange exceptions. It should be straightforward, shouldn't?

The error I'm getting is:

```
[ERROR] [project_name] - The java.util.Map parameterization is not simple, but the getConf method does not provide a delegate
```

I read the map like that:

```
final String jsObject = GeneralContextNativeReader.read("globalConf");
GlobalConfFactory globalConfFactory = GWT.create(GlobalConfFactory.class);
Map<String, String> globalConf = AutoBeanCodex.decode(globalConfFactory, Map.class, jsObject).as();
```

and the factory is defined as:

```
public interface GlobalConfFactory extends AutoBeanFactory {
    AutoBean<Map<String, String>> globalConf();
}
```

What is wrong with that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK `Maps` and `Lists` and other non simple objects can only be reference types and not value types. See [here](http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/wiki/AutoBean#Property_types) for more details.
Changing the code to this should make it work:

```
public interface Data {
   public Map<String,String>> getGlobalConf();
}

public interface DataFactory extends AutoBeanFactory {
   AutoBean<Data> getData();
}

final String jsObject = GeneralContextNativeReader.read("globalConf");
DataFactory dataFactory = GWT.create(DataFactory.class);
Data data = AutoBeanCodex.decode(dataFactory, Data.class, jsObject).as();
Map<String, String> globalConf = data.getGlobalConf();
```

Your json string has to look something like that:

```
{"globalConf":{ "element":"value","element2":"value2",...}}
```

Answer (score 0):

This can also happen if your AutoBean interface contains a static method (new in Java 8).